# Pass message from C to erlang

Tags: c, erlang, message

I try to send message from C code to erlang. I use EI Library.

My C code:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  erl_init (NULL, 0);

  extern const char *erl_thisnodename(void);
  extern short erl_thiscreation(void);

  #define SELF(fd) erl_mk_pid(erl_thisnodename(), fd, 0, erl_thiscreation())

  ETERM *arr[2], *emsg;

  int sockfd, creation=1;

  arr[0] = SELF(sockfd);
  arr[1] = erl_mk_atom("ok");
  emsg   = erl_mk_tuple(arr, 2);

  erl_reg_send(sockfd, "my_server", emsg);
  erl_free_term(emsg);

  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And my erlang code:

```
start() ->
    Pid = spawn(?MODULE, loop, []),
    register(my_server, Pid).

loop() ->
    receive
        {ok} ->
            io:format("Ok received \n"),
            loop();
        stop ->
            stop;
        _ ->
            io:format("Somethig else \n")
    end.    

stop() ->
    my_server ! stop.
```

But when i run my C application, erlang application nothing received. What's wrong?

I get error:

[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x08055fac in ei_mutex_lock ()

Thank you.

Comment: What does your debugger say?  Do you have a stack trace?

Answer (score 3):

At the very least, your C program passes an uninitialized variable (`sockfd`) to the `erl_mk_pid()` function, and again later in the call to `erl_reg_send()`.  That's probably a good place to start.